# Select hidden input by name attribute

Tags: jquery, input

I need to get data from a hidden field.  Due to constraints of the given system, I cannot specify by Id.  I'm given

```
<input type="hidden" value="knob" name="door">
```

and I try `var x = $("input[name='#Door']")[0].value;` but `x` gives an error:

> $(...)[0] is not defined

I've been kicking this for hours.  Suggestions wanted.

Comment: Clearly, the name is not `#Door`, but `door`.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon, someone already posted an answer below that says exactly that.

Comment: @IronFlare *"Use this:"* isn't exactly the same.... And the answer was wrong before the edit.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
var x = $("input[name='door']")[0].value;
```

As the another poster suggested you can use `$(...).val()`, and should do unless you have a specific reason to select only the first match.

Comment: I still get type error $(...)[0] is undefined.  Honestly, I cut and pasted.

Comment: The casing in Door and door doesn't match. See edit. Javascript is case sensitive. Door and door are not equal.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `.value` that is calling that property which is undefined.

Use `.val()`

Then you're calling `#Door` which doesn't exist.

Use `door` since that's the name of the input.

**Putting them together:**

```
<script>
  var x = $("input[name='door']").val();
  console.log(x);
</script>
```

**Update**

Didn't saw the `[0]`, using `.value` works fine. But since you're using Jquery why not use `.val()` instead.

Comment: Using the indexer [0] exposes the raw DOM element, so value should return the value of the input element.

Comment: @garryp updated my answer, didn't notice the [0] thing. Since he's using Jquery I automatically assume that.

Answer (score 0):

Problem in declaration only

[jquery name selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

You can select an element by name as : 
$("[name='value']"), so for your problem you can use `$("input[name='door']").val();`